# Xy-pic: Draw a partial circle segment with the command \cir

Tags: xy-pic

I can't figure out if is it possible or not to draw a partial circle segment
between to arbitrary direction, with the command `\cir`?

The manual says:

```
*\cir<radius>{<diag> <orient> <diag>}
```

I want to draw the part of the full circle, with radius 5mm, between the direction (4,1) and (1,4), so I use the command:

```
(0,0)*\cir<5mm>{v(4,1)^v(1,4)}
```

but it's completely wrong!

Which is the correct syntax?

Thanks.

---

Edit

Actually, the manual says that the part of the full circle is determined by the tangent vector [...].
So, in my example I need to calculate the dot products and than I get:

(4,-1) which is perpendicular to (1,4)

(1,-4) which is perpendicular to (4,1)

and than it would be:

```
(0,0)*\cir<5mm>{v(1,-4)^v(4,-1)}
```

Comment: You have to use `arc`. See the user guide.

Comment: @Sigur: I'm using XyJax (http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax/xyjax.html), which is an "almost"  Xy-pic compatible extension for MathJax, so `\arc` would be the right command if it was implemented. This is way I'm trying to achieve the same result with `\cir` (if possible).

Comment: so it is better to edit and  inform on the top that you are using some extra tools.

Comment: Did you see this user guide: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf (pg. 59)

Comment: @Sigur: Yes, I did. That is my reference. Since I can't use `\arc`, I'm trying to understand how to set a direction as described at page 14 section 4l.